# Dynamically scale font size to the size of a graph within an image with pyplot (Python)

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, size

I'm using pyplot to create a gallery of plotted curves, which are all essentially the same size, but the number of them can change. I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically scale the size of the text and the legend within each of the plots to the number of plots that are being produced, so it looks good when there's only 1 plot, but also looks good when there's 4 x 4 (16 total) plots.

Is this in any way possible?

Comment: The easiest way is to scale the figure size `fig.set_size_inches(3, 7)` or `fig, ax = plt.subplots(..., figsize=(5, 3))`.  If you want to keep the same number of pixels, scale DPI down.